# How to copy last 10 active rows instead of last active row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Currently i have a vba code that will copy the last active row with formulas and all and paste it in the next row under it. Instead i would like it to copy the last 10 active rows and paste them under it. Can someone help me tweak my current code to help allow this?

```
    'Sub RunMost()

       Dim ws As Worksheet


           For Each ws In Sheets
            If ws.Name = ("Sheet1") Then
              ws.Activate

    ' Go to last cell
    Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select

    ' Copy formula from cell above
    Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
    Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
  End If
  Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `Rows(Selection.Row - 1)` with `Rows(Selection.Row - 10)`?

Comment: I recommend reading through [how to avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) which should shed some light on this. I believe if you read through this, you can at least *start* tweaking the above to loop.  And also @Dave's suggestion...

Comment: range(rows(selection.row-11),rows(selection.row-1)).copy

Comment: yes @Dave i did try that and instead it only selects the 10th row

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that worked! thank you!

Comment: Try @Nathan_Sav's solution

Answer (score 0):

`range(rows(selection.row-11),rows(selection.row-1)).copy`